# fetching images from default gallery in a custom dialog and display

Tags: android, customdialog

I am trying to fetch an image from the default android gallary and set it to the the imageview in a custom dialog . I have tried using

startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);

but gives an error at startActivityForResult()

please suggest a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static final int=GALLERY_REQUEST=2001;

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Choose a Picture");

    startActivityForResult(chooser, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

//Getting result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

       imageView.setImageUri(data.getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: startActivityForResult does not work when the layout is a custom dialog,Could you please suggest an alternative

Comment: Are you starting gallery from custom dialog?

Comment: Yes, thats the requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
   //decalare in manifest
   <activity
        android:name=".MyDialogActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_share"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth">
    </activity>

 MyDialogActivity extends Activity{

 onCreate(Bundle svd) {

    setContentView(R.layout.customdialogview);
 }

}
```

It will create a dialog for you and u can use my above code in this activity.

Comment: Anyways, changed the dialog to activity and now it should work

Comment: Actually, Dialog is also an activity. And you ought to marks this answer.